# TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:'... when saving a model with custom layer ONLY in Google cloud platform

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I implemented a neural network consisting of a custom layer `GlobalWeightedAveragePooling` described below. The following error occurred when saving the model in Google Cloud Platform, while successfully saving the model in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m3Vh-P20o41kzwu7tgd0TYmF8iW4r7Hu#scrollTo=p1-ySEpYwArD). I searched for multiple Github issues, suggesting several solutions but none I have tried solved this issue. What might be some possible issues of this only happening in GCP? (Perhaps version issues, cudnn setup, OS compatibility...)

```
class GlobalWeightedAveragePooling(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    #Implementation of GlobalWeightedAveragePooling
    def __init__(self,kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.01),**kwargs):
        #self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        super(GlobalWeightedAveragePooling, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_initializer =kernel_initializer
        super(GlobalWeightedAveragePooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        #input_shape=(w,h,c)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",shape=input_shape[1:],initializer=self.kernel_initializer)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({'kernel': self.kernel})
        return config
    
    def call(self, input):
        com=tf.math.multiply(input, self.kernel)
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(com,axis=[1,2])

model.save('./logs/weights', save_format='tf')
```

Error message

```
...
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/json_utils.py", line 50, in default
    return serialization.get_json_type(obj)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/serialization.py", line 79, in get_json_type
    raise TypeError('Not JSON Serializable:', obj)

TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Variable 'global_weighted_average_pooling_1/kernel:0' shape=(6, 6, 448) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.01235585,  0.00958068, -0.01888468, ..., -0.01521709,
          0.0061503 , -0.0146472 ],
        [ 0.00336177, -0.00686159,  0.01115836, ...,  0.00540031,
          0.00579884, -0.00464661],
        [-0.00188815, -0.00527825,  0.00524037, ...,  0.00175391,
```

Comment: @FonyLew The problem is model.save works without error in another environment: Google Colab.

Comment: @krenerd which products do you mean when you say GCP?

Comment: @R.Esteves `Jupyter IPython Notebook VM` with 1 T4 GPU setup by default. I would also like to provide some more specific machine specs but can't find more info. This error is still constantly happening in GCP. What might be some common reasons of such environmental-specific issues? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @R.Esteves Is there a way to provide some sort of sharable link of my GCP notebook?

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=958003&template=1525607